# Can We use AJAX Toolkit controls in ASP.NET Repeater Control

Tags: controls, repeater

Can we use AJAX Toolkit Autocomplete control in ASP.NET Repeater Control.

Can't we add it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it, and you could add it to the control at runtime, just like any other control.